How to identify people gaming the system
Open water swimming races are conducted using a handicap system. Slowest swimmers leave first and fastest leave last allowing everyone an opportunity to come home first and win. The handicap is decided based on the recorded pace of the swimmer from previous races in minutes:seconds per 100m and what the distance of the race will be. An example range of paces is (faster swimmer) 1:20/100m - (slower swimmer) 2:50/100m - they can be higher and lower than this of course.
Examples:
Over a 1200m race a swimmer with a 2:30/100m pace would take 30 minutes to complete.
Over a 1200m race a swimmer with a 1:30/100m pace would take 18 minutes to complete so they could get a handicap of 12 minutes.
Over a 1600m race a swimmer with a 2:30/100m pace would take 40 minutes to complete.
Over a 1600m race a swimmer with a 1:30/100m pace would take 24 minutes to complete so they could get a handicap of 16 minutes.
Any given race can greatly influence the pace an individual swimmer can achieve as currents, waves etc can vary and impact swimmers differently. For example ordinarily a swimmer may be a 2:00/100m swimmer but in a river with a current in their favour they may be a 1:30/100m swimmer and everyone else is equally affected.
Nefarious swimmers may deliberately swim slowly to attract a more favourable handicap and one day decide to swim at their actual pace to win a race i.e. pretend they are slow, get an advantageous handicap and then swim fast to win a race (after which their handicap will be increased but its too late then). These nefarious swimmers may bide their time to wait for a race of notoriety to take their opportunity.
Given a result set per race like this:
Course Length (m), SwimmerID, handicap (MM:SS), swim time (MM:SS), race time (MM:SS)
where swim time is the actual time in the water and race time is the handicap adjusted time e.g. in the water for 20:00 with a 5:00 handicap would be a 25:00 race time.
Note, not all swimmers participate in all races.
Could anyone recommend an analysis that could assist in identifying alleged nefarious swimmers?

How can someone swimming 40 minutes win over someone swimming 24 minutes? Why would you penalize faster swimmers? This will have exactly the effect that you describe, faster swimmers swimming slower so as not to be penalized. They might swim fast until the finish line and then wait until the second person is close before crossing the finish line, etc.

The spirit of the competition is everyone trying their best and everyone having a chance to win. If it was fastest wins it would be the same swimmers on the podium every race. There are other race series like that but this one is not interested in that.

OK, can you change these rules or are you merely tasked with identifying these "cheaters" with the current rules?

I cannot change the rules the objective is to identify the "cheaters"

With the current rules this might not be that easy (especially if the swimmers are gaming the system big time). For starters you could compute some sort of ratio duration/length for each swimmer and each race which should give you some distribution of what to expect for each swimmer. When you obtain a new measure you can compare it to this distribution and see if it is quite far off from expectation.

The data science problem is not very interesting. It is a typical problem where you don't have labels and try to work around this by making assumptions. Theoretically no one could be cheating, or everyone could be and it is impossible to know just by the observation. Perhaps compare the swimmer time distributions to other swimming competitions which don't have handicap? But it looks like it could be posed as a fun math problem. Is it worth cheating? What strategy maximizes the expected number of wins? What is the Nash Equilibrium? You could try asking this on math.stackexchange.com.
